# Lithium Auth adapter, how to reach the Controller / Request?

Tags: php, facebook, lithium

I'm trying to build a `Facebook` Auth adapter.
Inside it, i need to get my hand on the `Request` object to retreive request query parameters.

I've added this in my plugin bootstrap :

```
<?php
use lithium\action\Dispatcher;
use facebook\extensions\adapter\security\auth\Facebook;

Dispatcher::applyFilter('_callable', function($self, $params, $chain) {

    //debug(compact('self', 'params', 'chain'));
    Facebook::$request = $params['request'];

    // Always make sure to keep the filter chain going.
    $response = $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);

    return $response;
});
```

Then i have access to the $request in my Facebook class (under `check()` for instance) using `self::$request`. But it seems wrong somehow.

Same situation when i try to redirect my user, i can't see how i can access a Controller & `lithium\action\Controller::redirect()` is not static.

I'm new to this whole filter thing, can someone tell me that this is the correct implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple finally, i just passed `$this->request` as a parameter of the Auth::check, does the trick.